# ad hoc version exits immediately when try to load the app to memory

Tags: iphone

I have an app, it worked well on simulator, but the ad hoc version always exit after Default.png launched and started to run on my ipod.

I try to check if there is any problem concerns

```
•   Case sensitivity.  
•   Read/write bundle files.  
•   Memory Leak
```

But everything look likes Ok. The app occupies memory no more than 800K.
I set the breakpoints anywhere but it still exits before debugger reaches them.
No crash reported.

**There is an interest thing if I set 1 or more NSAlertView and show in viewDidLoad of rootController(UITabBarController), it will work correctly!**

It is my first time to use UITabBarController, I always construct my self's multi viewcontrollers.

I am not sure if this problem relates to the usage of UITabBarController.

My Xcode 3.1.4
os x is 10.6.5

I have sticked on for 3,4 days.

Welcome any comment

Thanks
interdev

Comment: Are there any crash logs showing up in the device logs section of the organizer ? Are you using an ad-hoc distribution profile.. have you tried a development profile ?

Comment: When stuff like this happens, it helps to look at the device console (Xcode -> Organizer -> *Device Name* -> Console, or the same thing in iPCU if Xcode is showing a blank console.) "Default.png" is neither launched nor run; it's just an image. Chances are your app is never actually "launched".

Comment: I ran into an issue where a dev had linked the SenTesting framework to the build. Might be worth investigating if anything similar is on your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a provisioning issue. It will do this exactly if there is a certificate problem - display the load screen - then just abort. This happens, for example, if the certificates are expired.

It *will* however tell you that this is happening on the console. Run with your iDevice connected - open the Organizer - view the console - try running. See if it complains about the certificate on launch.

If not - the console will probably tell you *something*...

Answer (score 0):

Usually your Ad-hoc build settings will specify an Entitlements.plist file which disables debugging via the `get-task-allow` setting. This is to stop your users from being able to debug/inspect memory etc. while they are testing your app. If the app works with your Debug build then this is the most likely explanation.